# Getting a page viewed at 5past 1 in the morning

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, cron, automation

Is it possible to (perhaps by using a cron job) to have a page viewed at a specific time to enable a JavaScript script to run to perform an action?
This page uses a redirect to pass data to other php scripts.

EDIT: 1:05am

Comment: Yes, sorry for ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you meant 1:05am.

Use [`.getMinutes()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getminutes.asp) and [`.getHours()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp).

```
var currentDate = new Date();
if(currentDate.getHours() == 5 && currentDate.getMinutes() == 5) {
    // run some code    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a cron you could add something like this to your crontab:

```
5 1 * * * wget -q -t 1 -O - http://www.yoursite.com/cronjob.php
```

This will request `http://www.yoursite.com/cronjob.php` every day at 1:05am. It will however *not* run Javascript embedded on the page.

If you need to run the Javascript on the page, you should take a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set cron job to visit specific web page on some predefined time

```
// cron format
seconds minutes hours days months years
```

Cron format may change depending on server provider (Amazon Web Service don't allow seconds)

So to visit your page at 01:05 every day:

```
* 1 5 * * *
```

Add specify what page to visit (setup will be different depending on server provider).

Cron Job may be used for very long script execution (since it's using CLI), just instead of accessing page directly via `http`, access it as file. E.g.: `var\www\current\myScript.php`. It will ignore execution time limits.

Comment: is the Var of any significance? @Justinas

Comment: @JBithell no, it's just AWS path to file